# Is it possible for Google Cloud Messaging to remove a message from Android Notification Center?

Tags: android, cloud, messaging

Looking for some ideas: 
I have an app that is receiving notifications from the Google Cloud Messaging Center...
My android device receives the notification, call it notification A, and notification A gets displayed in the notification messaging queue.  (This is at the OS level).

Is it possible, server side, to send another notification call it notification B, to remove notification A from the devices notification queue.

I'm assuming this is not possible; 
My issue is that notifications can expire, and if they are expired they should no longer be in the android notification queue.

Any thoughts?

Thank!
Best Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the use case of the new [Device Group Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications), which allows you update the state on all the users devices based on their action (i.e., dismiss on one dismisses on all others) or a server side change (your expiration).

Comment: #ianhanniballake thank you for your response! 

So it is possible to remove a notification from an Android Devices Notification queue via the will of the server

For example: 
Notification A gets pushed to the device; and sitting inside of the notification queue on the device... Server decides at will that the notification has expired so server pushes a kill message to a particular device to remove the message from the message queue. (Possible with the use of GCM Cloud Connection Server ?)

Comment: @chocospaz - that's correct. I'd suggest watching the [Google I/O 2013 GCM presentation](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/324893448) to learn more about this functionality and how it might work for your app.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am afraid Google have made all your links die. I'm having trouble finding the point in their doucmentation which talks about recalling/retracting a message (i.e. editing the text, or changing the expiry date to be sooner, when a message has been delivered to - but not yet displayed on - a device). Is this what you were originally referring to? Thanks.

Comment: @MagnusSmith - I've updated the link to Device Group Messaging - basically you're building the logic yourself, you just get the automatic fan out to all of the user's device and the ability to send upstream messages from one device to the others (such as when a notification is dismissed)

Comment: Thank you for responding, I appreciate it. The upstream message capability wasn't quite the same as being able to edit a pending notification, which I was struggling to find mention of online. Probably it can't be done...yet I'm sure I read about it....somewhere.

Comment: @MagnusSmith - assuming you are building your own notification (then calling something like `notificationManager.notify()`), you can override/update a notification by calling it again using the same id.

Comment: Aha! Found it at last: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref has mention of the 'tag' part of the payload which you control server-side. Sadly it is Android only. "If set, and a notification with the same tag is already being shown, the new notification replaces the existing one in Android notification center."